# How can I fix the even/odd child classes comments so that the comments are unaffected by the top-level even/odd?

Tags: theme-development, comments, templates, css, comments-template

Sorry if the title was confusing, I'm having a bit of trouble explaining here. I'm working on a theme for my site, and I'm using a slightly modified version of a custom comments template found [here](http://themeshaper.com/2012/11/04/the-wordpress-theme-comments-template/). The style I have in mind for comments is this:

1. Top Level comment 1

   **1. Child comment 1**

   *2. child comment 2*

   **3. Child comment 3**
2. Top level comment 2
3. Top level comment 3

AKA I want the child comments to be even/odd, but I want the main thread comments all to be alike. My problem is that when a new comment is added at the top, the child comments get offset. So instead of being the above, it turns into:

1. Top Level comment 1

   *1. Child comment 1*

   **2. child comment 2**

   *3. Child comment 3*
2. Top level comment 2
3. Top level comment 3

Which is undesirable. How can I make it so the child even/odd classes are unaffected by new main comments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.even` & `.odd` class styles from style.css
and use CSS psudo classes.

```
.comment:nth-child(2n) {
    your styles for even
}

.comment:nth-child(2n+1) {
    your styles for odd
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, but I can't figure out how to make the `nth-child` carry over to all of the child comments. They end up affecting every element that is a child, and not just the `<article>` tags I want changed.